# Android: How to link parse.com to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am working on ParseFacebookUser. From its documentation, I coded the facebook login module as follows:

### Code:

```
@Override  
    protected void onResume() 
    {  
        super.onResume();  
        ....

        Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "XXX"); 
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

        // FB: Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "user_location", "user_friends", "email", "public_profile");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() 
        {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) 
              {
                    if (user == null) 
                    {
                        Log.d("MyApp","Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } 
                    else if (user.isNew()) 
                    {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }
              }
        });


    }
```

### Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.abc.user.LoginActivity"             android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.abc.user.RegisterActivity"              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.abc.user.User_leaderboard"              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>   
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" /> />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>   

    </application>
```

### Logcat:

```
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542): Caused by: Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest.
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:381)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:261)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:155)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationProvider.logInAsync(ParseAuthenticationProvider.java:50)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInAsync(ParseFacebookUtils.java:265)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:161)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:173)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at com.abc.abc.First.onResume(First.java:144)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1210)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5512)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2948)
07-12 01:13:57.488: E/AndroidRuntime(23542):    ... 12 more
```

### Question:

Caused by: Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest. There is no page redirect to login of facebook. What is wrong in the above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have not included the activity for Facebook login in the Manifest file. Add this.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Refer [Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) for more information.